# Bind list to gridview C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, list, datagridview

I'm trying to bind list to `gridview`. Situation is like this: I take data from .txt file, later I put it inside first list `List<Mycolumns>`. I have data in list (with 3 separated columns) that I created. I am taking data from one of the columns called `System_Description`. Now I would like  to show this data in `gridview`, but only thing that I get is length of each row. How should I fix it? Here is my code.

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<MyColumns> list = new List<MyColumns>();

        OpenFileDialog openFile1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFile1.Multiselect = true;

        if (openFile1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            foreach (string filename in openFile1.FileNames)
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string[] _columns = line.Split(",".ToCharArray());
                        MyColumns mc = new MyColumns();
                        mc.Time = _columns[0];
                        mc.System_Description = _columns[1];
                        mc.User_Description = _columns[2];
                        list.Add(mc);
                    }
                }
            }
            DataTable ListAsDataTable = BuildDataTable<MyColumns>(list);
            DataView ListAsDataView = ListAsDataTable.DefaultView;
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = view = ListAsDataView;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        }

        List<string> description = list.Select(x => x.System_Description).ToList<string>();
        this.dataGridView2.DataSource = description;

    }
class MyColumns
{
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string System_Description { get; set; }
    public string User_Description { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:

I've read that `DataBind()` works for Web form, my app is desktop app. What should I do now?

Comment: one thing you should do is to bind data to BindingSource and then assign that to DataSource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. I did it this way, maybe it will help someone. You can use DataTable and then bind DT to gridview.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("values");

foreach(string items in description)
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    dt.Rows.Add(items);
}
this.dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource(list);`

Answer (score 0):

You are only selecting the `System_Description` field using the following statement:

```
List<string> description = list.Select(x => x.System_Description).ToList<string>();
```

Then you are binding this list to the gridview:

```
this.dataGridView2.DataSource = description;
```

If you want to bind the whole data to the `gridview`; just bind the list as a datasource.

```
this.dataGridView2.DataSource = list;
this.dataGridView2.DataBind();
```

Comment: Yes, I know this, but when I bind my description list to gridview it shows length of each line inside, not data that it holds. That is the problem.

Comment: after this you have to call DataBind method. this.dataGridView2.DataBind();

Comment: @KarthikAMR you are right; I assumed that the code already has a bind statement.

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
 this.dataGridView1.DataSource = description;
```

and add Bound field in gridview on aspx.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="System_Description" HeaderText="System_Description"></asp:BoundField>
```